# Windows server backup fails at 40%

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I´m configuring windows server backup as full system backup. It starts fine, but when it´s making system drive (c:) backup it stops at 40% every time i try.
It only backups 7.28 GB of the total 18.19 GB.
I tried changing destination drive and also checking c: filesystem in order to find any problem, but it seems to be ok and the problem is still the same.
I got a message telling that the backup is completed with warnings. The warning details says that it didn´t complete backup because of input/output error in source or destination.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do the System event logs show things like disk errors?

Comment: No, there are no disk errors, neither filesystem errors.

Comment: Where (or what) is the destination drive? Might it be another device on the network?

Comment: I tried different destinations, 2 network drives and one external drive.

Comment: Do the drives being backed up have enough free drive space to do a Volume Shadow Copy?

Comment: Hi, yes it has almost 4 times the original whole disk size free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally real problem appeared.
System hard drive has erro blocks. At first times diks checks seemed to be ok, but finally OS didn´t boot after one upgrade, so testing hard drive with HDDRegenerator i could find several blocks with errors. HDDregenerator fixed the block apparently but the errors cames again.
After changing the hard drive and reinstalling it makes system backup fine.
Thanks.